# Как отфильтровать строки по параметрам значений столбцов(Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Я хочу отфильтровать строки по определенному значению в столбцах - взять только те строки, где 'race' == 'Black' и 'age' > 40:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого я использую:

```
print(df[df['age'] > 40])
print(df[df['race']=='Black'])
print(df['race']=='Black')
```

По параметру'age' всё ок, но по 'race' показывает False, хотя здесь есть 'Black'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что нужно исправить, чтобы фильтровалось и по 'race' == 'Black' тоже?

Comment: проверяйте значения в таблице - пробелы, не английские буквы и тп

Comment: можно так попробовать, чтоб убедиться, что все одинаково написаны`df[df['race']==df.loc[3,'race']]`

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо, это работает, насколько я понимаю это берет значение в 3 строке для данного столбца и применяет его ко всему столбцу проводя фильтрование?

Comment: @splash58 по поводу синтаксиса - я тоже думал и проверял и переписывал несколько раз,  но не нашел где ошибка. С int работает как надо, с object - не работает

Comment: проблема не с синтаксисом, а со значением. посмотрите вот на это `print(df.loc[3,'race'])`

Comment: вот так еще  можно проверить, что black так написан `df['race'].str.contains('Black')` Скорее всего, пробелы

Comment: Заявочка в биокад?))

Comment: Дайте пример исходных данных в электронном виде. Скорее всего, splash прав, вам нужно рафинировать данные.

Comment: df['race'].unique().tolist() - покажет список всех уникальных значений. Это поможет понять какие конкретно у вас значения

Comment: Спасибо всем, я нашел ошибку - пробел, но метод @splash58 тоже прекрасно подошел